# Unity2D Smooth Rotation using Slerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a patrol script for a game object. I want the object to rotate smoothly and slowly to face it's patrol target.

Unfortunately, the object snaps to it's new location.

I've asked on unity forums and can't get an answer.

How can I get the rotation to be smooth and slow?

Here's my code.

```
    public Transform[] patrol;
    public int Currentpoint;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Vector3 john = new Vector3(0,1,0);
    public Vector3 targetLocation;

    void Start()
    {

    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position == patrol [Currentpoint].position) {
        Currentpoint++;
        if (Currentpoint >= patrol.Length) {
            Currentpoint = 0;
        }
        targetLocation = patrol [Currentpoint].position;
        Vector3 targetDir = targetLocation - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (targetDir.y, targetDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.SlerpUnclamped (transform.localRotation, Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle, Vector3.forward), Time.deltaTime * 3);
        Debug.Log (Currentpoint);
    }

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, patrol [Currentpoint].position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

public static Quaternion Slerp(Quaternion a, Quaternion b, float t); The parameter t is clamped to the range [0, 1]

your times 3 is throwing it out so it is not between 0-1 ... I believe

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately when I change the paramater t to a value in between 0-1 the object stops rotating at all.

Comment: When you run (with breakpoints) what is the transforms rotation between your slerp call and the movetowards at the end

Answer (score 0):

If you like some mathematics then I have a solution for you.

You want to rotate object around another, like Earth and Sun. May be some other solutions may available but I would do it through LookAt and parametric equation of circle.

`x = r * cos(theta) + displacementX`

`y = r * sin(theta) + displacementY`

where `r` is radius, distance in your case
`displacementX` and `displacementY` are the distance from origin. If both (`displacementX` and `displacementY`) is 0 then it will rotate around `origin (0,0)`. In other words `displacementX` and `displacementY` is the origin of rotation.

In Object(Earth) script, do it as follow

```
public Transform _sun;
float _theta = 0;

void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine ("ChangeAngle");
}

void Update ()
{
    transform.LookAt (_sun);
    float newX = (5 * Mathf.Cos (_theta)) + _sun.position.x;
    float newY = (5 * Mathf.Sin (_theta)) + _sun.position.y;

    transform.position = new Vector3 (newX, newY, _sun.position.z);
}

IEnumerator ChangeAngle ()
{
    while (true) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.01f);
        _theta += 0.1f;
        if (_theta >= 360)
            _theta = 0;
    }
}
```

You can further play with it

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer,

It turns out that placing the rotational instructions within the if statement was the problem. I converted the rotation to a function, then placed the function above the general patrol movement in the same loop segment.

I don't know why it worked.

Thanks to everyone for their help.